# static file are not working in django nginx

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have created one small app, and uploaded to the aws server, i can see everything is working except static folder, my static folder is under the `/home/ubuntu/django-bhuriyo/mysite/` this directory, i am using `nginx`, i have put my code  of nginx conf and settings.py, can anyone please look my code and help me to resolve this issue ?

django.conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ****.amazonaws.com;

        location /static {
                alias /home/ubuntu/django-bhuriyo/mysite;
        }

        location /  {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/django-bhuriyo/app.sock;
        }

}
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL  = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/django-bhuriyo/mysite'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see everything fine... are you collecting the files?

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

You need that command for Django to copy over all your static files to the directory specified in the `STATIC_ROOT` setting. Remember you have to execute that every time you have some change in your static files.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to declare the path of the media.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and location for nginx :

```
  location = /media/ {
        root /path/to/medias;
    }
```

what is your error traceback ?