# Nginx not finding static files in Dockered Django app in Azure Web App for containers

Tags: django, azure, docker, nginx, azure-web-app-for-containers

I managed to run my Django app locally with docker compose( Django container + Nginx container) and it works fine, but when i want to run it in Azure web app for containers nginx can't find the ressources.
I don't know if i should change some configuration so it can work in Azure services or i need to enable ports in azure app settings therefore my containers could communicate.

This is my nginx configuration (nginx.conf) :

```
upstream myapp {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name myappname.azurewebsites.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/web/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/app/web/media/;
    }

}
```

I don't know why it did work locally when i run docker compose but in azure web app nginx can't find static files.

Please let me know if I need to clarify or include anything else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Joseba S.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62007834/15969115) . Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

> You need that command for Django to copy over all your static files to the directory specified in the STATIC_ROOT setting. Remember you have to execute that every time you have some change in your static files.

Spin down the development containers:

```
$ docker-compose down -v
```

Test:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --build
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec web python manage.py migrate --noinput
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec web python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
```

You can also verify in the logs via `docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml logs -f`  that requests to the static files are served up successfully via Nginx.

You can refer to [Dockerizing Django with Postgres, Gunicorn, and Nginx](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/), [Cannot locate static files after deploying with docker](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/cannot-locate-static-files-after-deploying-with-docker/5889) and [Nginx failing to serve django static or media files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67358657/nginx-failing-to-serve-django-static-or-media-files-on-digital-ocean)

Comment: [Nginx failing to serve django static or media files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67358657/nginx-failing-to-serve-django-static-or-media-files-on-digital-ocean) helped me figuring out my problem. I needed to change the host port in my nginx container from 1337 to 80 because port 1337 is not allowed in azure i guess. Thank you @DeepDave-MT.